# (iPhone, OpenGL) direct texture data storage in files

Tags: ios, performance, opengl-es, textures

At this moment I use this scenario to load OpenGL texture from PNG:

- load PNG via UIImage
- get pixels data via bitmap context
- repack pixels to new format (currently RGBA8 -> RGBA4, RGB8 -> RGB565, using ARM NEON instructions)
- create OpenGL texture with data

(this approach is commonly used in Cocos2d engine)

It takes much time and seems to do extra work that may be done once per build. So I want to save repacked pixels data back into file and load it directly to OpenGL on second time.

I would know the practical advantages. Does anyone tried it? Is it worth to compress data via zip (as I know, current iDevices have bottleneck in file access)? Would be very thankful for real experience sharing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have made some successful experiment:

I compress texture data by `zlib` (max compression ratio) and save it to file (via `NSData` methods). The size of file is much smaller then PNG in some cases.

As for loading time, I can't say exact timestamps because in my project there are 2 parallel threads - one is loading textures on background while another is still rendering scene. **It is approximately twice faster** - IMHO the main reason is that we copy image data directly to OpengGL without repacking, and input data amount smaller).

PS: Build optimization level plays very high role in loading time: about 4 seconds in debug configuration vs. 1 second in release.

Answer (score 1):

Even better, if these are pre-existing images, compress them using PowerVR Texture Compression (PVRTC). PVRTC textures can be loaded directly, and are stored on the GPU in their compressed form, so they can be much smaller than the various raw pixel formats.

I provide an example of how to compress and use PVRTC textures in [this sample code](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/CubeExample.zip) (the texture coordinates are a little messed up there, because I haven't corrected them yet). In that example, I just reuse Apple's PVRTexture sample class for handling this type of texture. The PVRTC textures are compressed via a script that's part of one of the build phases, so this can be automated for your various source images.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I can't use PVR format (it brings some visible artifacts on transparent pixels, and images must be of POT size)

Comment: @brigadir: WRT the artefacts, what compression tool are you using, are you using premultiplied (i.e (1, 1-SrcAlpha) blend) or non-premultiplied (SrcAlpha, 1-SrcAlpha), and what RGBs are actually in the transparent areas? The last part of the question is because I've seen all sorts of bizarre colours stuffed into otherwise invisible areas of example textures that the compressor will *try* to represent.

Answer (score -1):

Ignore any advice about PVRTC, that stuff is only useful for 3D textures that have limited color usage. It is better to just use 24 or 32 BPP textures from real images. If you would like to see a real working example of the process you describe then take a look at [load-opengl-textures-with-alpha-channel-on-ios](http://iosgraphicsanimation.wordpress.com/2013/06/15/load-opengl-textures-with-alpha-channel-on-ios/). The example shows how texture data can be compressed with 7zip (much better than zip) when attached to the app resource, but then the results are decompressed and saved to disk in an optimal format that can be directly sent to the video card without further pixel component rearranging. This example uses a POT texture, but it would not be too hard to adapt to non-POT and to use the Apple optimizations so that the texture data need not be explicitly copied into the graphics card. Those optimizations are already implemented when sending video data to CoreGraphics.